# Bash script to identify which processes are launched on system start-up

Tags: bash, process, system, startup

Need a script in Bash that identifies which are the processes lunched when system start-up and then:

- Print them in the order in which they were launched;
- Print them by ordering them according to the CPU consumption they have made.

What could be the solution?

I tried with the commands

```
ps -e -opid, lstart, cmd,% cpu
```

and various combinations, but nothing.

Comment: What OS ? Do you use `systemd` ?

Comment: @iamauser unix OS